# How to get elementaryOS Odin 6.0 FlatPak Apps to Use the system Dark Theme?

Tags: themes, release-odin, flatpak

I installed elementary OS 6.0 Odin (final release 2021-08-10).

I was finally able to get FlatPak apps to install. However, none use the elementary OS Dark Theme. I checked FlatPak and the elementary theme is installed. How do you get Odin to use the Dark Theme system wide for all FlatPak apps?

Answer (score 2):

I also needed to install a dark theme to flatpak with

```
flatpak install flathub org.gtk.Gtk3theme.Adwaita-dark
```

Then using

```
flatpak list
```

to get the application ID...  Then the following command to apply the theme to the application ID... For example with LibreOffice

```
flatpak override --user --env=GTK_THEME=Adwaita-dark org.libreoffice.LibreOffice
```

That command worked great in Hera, but it seems to be hit or miss in Odin.  It will hold for a while... even occasionally after a reboot, but ultimately it seems to lose the setting and default back to the flatpaks "light" setting.

Adding `GTK_THEME=Adwaita-dark` as an Environment Variable in Flatseal seems to yeild the same results.  Works for a while but in Odin, it seems to disappear.  In Hera it appears permanent.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! So far worked with the apps I tried, especially Pitivi, which I now need to use in the middle of the night :D

Answer (score 1):

You can force to use dark stylesheet using Pantheon Tweaks which will create new local settings under `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` with content below.

```
[Settings]
gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme=1
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's another approach:

"[Uniform theme and fonts for Qt apps in GTK environments](https://discovery.endeavouros.com/applications/uniform-theme-and-fonts-for-qt-apps-in-gtk-environments/2021/05/)" provided by the EndeavourOS-guys:
Instead of the the given arch-linux install cmd ('pacman -S *pkg-name*') you have to replace it with your normal install cmd ('apt install *pkg-name*'), and then follow the given instructions for user-space-setup (quickest).

Comment: Sorry, but the question is about `flatpak`, while your answer uses `apt`. Moreover, the issue is with all apps, including GTK apps like Pitivi. This is `flatpak`-specific issue, really.